# How can I check if a date for a rent is overdue? The rent is overdue after 30 days

Tags: java, date

```
Date rentDate = new Date(2323223232L);
Date currentDate = new Date();
if(rentDate.compareTo(currentDate)<30){
    System.out.println("OVERDUE!!!");
}
```

I want to check if this rent date for a bike is overdue. It becomes overdue 30 days after the rent date.

Comment: Please add more details to explain your question. This is not enough.

Comment: I'm guessing Java? (based on `System.out.println`)

Comment: Yes. This is Java.

Comment: What problem are you facing with that? conversion?

Comment: Don't use `Date`, use `java.time`

Comment: Please search. If you don’t find an exact match, you can certainly piece a solution together from what you find. Similar questions have been asked and answered over and over. Only avoid pages using the long outdated and poorly designed classes `Calendar` and — yes — `Date`. I even think this is simple as going through [the Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Never use the `java.util.Date` class, replaced by `java.time.Instant`. Never use `java.sql.Date`, replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    LocalDate rentDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 15);
    LocalDate dueDate = rentDate.plusDays(30);
    if (dueDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Malta")))) {
        System.out.println("Overdue; was due on " + dueDate);
    }
```

When I ran it just now, it printed:

> Overdue; was due on 2019-04-14

Please make sure you specify the desired time zone since it is never the same date everywhere on Earth.

Tip: Avoid shouting and exclamation marks in messages. Some users will feel bad about them, and they really don’t add anything helpful to the message. The user will understand the message fine without them.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.